# Outlook meeting Accept/Decline buttons are disabled

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I receive a meeting invitation in MS Outlook 2010 Professional Plus, the Accept, Tentative, Decline, and Propose New Time buttons are disabled, grayed out.

I've tried repairing my PST file, creating a new one, to no avail. Even when launching Outlook in safe mode they're not available.

When I right click on the meeting invitation in the message list view, the Accept menu option is available. When I click it, it crashes Outlook with exception code c0000005. It crashes Outlook whether I'm in safe mode or not.

Comment: What kind of email account is it (POP3, IMAP, Exchange?)  If you make a new Outlook profile, does it work as expected?  Have you tried the Change/Repair functionality for Office in Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Do you happen to have a delegate set to receive your meeting requests?